# how to use a proxy connection with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, proxy-authentication

I'm trying to run a "hello world" application in android studio. My connection is via proxy. When I try run the "hello world app", android studio show me the next error:

> Error running Prueba: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again.

If I configure in: "File/setting -> HTTP Proxy" and next put my proxy configuration, the error is the next:

> Error:Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.12.2/gradle-0.12.2.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
>   `<a href="toggle.offline.mode">Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project</a>`

How can I fix that error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There error indicates that proxy authentication is needed.  To authenticate to your proxy server go back to File->Setting->HTTP Proxy, check the box for Proxy authentication and enter your credentials there.  Also, click the check connection button to test that your connection is successful.

Comment: well, i put the credential and when i press "test connection" it say " connection succefally"... so, when i try run the program trhow the last error messenge in the publication up.

Comment: @GogoMix that's right because "Standalone SDK Manager" is separate from the File -> Settings -> HTTP Proxy. If you want to use those HTTP proxy settings, then don't use the standalone SDK manager

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio 1.4 there are two places, the proxy must be configured: First in Android Studio like Mike described in his answer. And second in the external SDK Manager:

Android Studio | Tools | Android | SDK-Manager |  Launch Standalone SDK Manager | Tools | Options

After setting the proxy in the SDK Manager, too, the issue was fixed.

Comment: It was driving me crazy because I had the http proxy settings entered, thanks to your answer I understood that the standalone sdk manager uses different settings. At work, I was unable to get the http proxy settings for the standalone sdk manager to work so I stopped using it.