# Cannot build for android using react-native

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to run react-native run-android but I continuously get this error.I am running on emulator . I started the app using `react-native init`.

**PS: I am running on proxy.**

When I am trying to run

> react-native run-android

I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*  What went wrong:
 A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'.
 > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
 > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
 Required by:
     :AwesomeProject:unspecified
  > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tool
/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/buil
 /gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: 
 Proxy Authentication Required
```

When I am trying to run

> directly in Android Studio

I get:

```
Error:Could not GET 
'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-
2.2.3.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication 
 Required
<a href="toggle.offline.mode">Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync 
project</a>
```

I have my node_modules installed and I'm not sure what else to try, I've been googling for the last 4 hours and have come up with nothing.

Comment: You have a Proxy Authentication

Comment: for android studio check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916951/how-to-use-a-proxy-connection-with-android-studio

Comment: The problem is actually quite simple; Your computer can't retrieve the server that has the gradle build tools (no matter you if you use Studio or React Native to compile). Simply using a VPN, or a different internet connection should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

set your proxy details Inside sdk manager

> AndroidStudio->tools->Android->SDKManager->system settings->Http Proxy

Comment: please check connection as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26919995/5706413

Comment: I did auto detect proxy settings.

Comment: connection successful

Answer (score 2):

your problem is not related to npm and node. you have some gradle problems.check if you can access the URL from browser?

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-
2.2.3.pom

Comment: Yes, I can access the link. Now can you please tell me what can be the problem and how to correct it ?

Answer (score 2):

It clearly says `<a href="toggle.offline.mode">Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync 
project</a>`. 
Have you tried enabling offline mode?
If not, try this:

Go to File -> Settings.

And open the 'Build,Execution,Deployment',Then open the 'Build Tools' -> 'Gradle'.

Then uncheck "Offline work" on the right.

Click the 'OK' button.

Then Rebuild the Project.

For Mac go to AndroidStudio -> Preferences, rest is same.

ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30794890/2895571

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these in your gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxyURL
systemProp.http.proxyPort=proxyPort
systemProp.http.proxyUser=USER
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=PASSWORD
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxyUrl 
systemProp.https.proxyPort=proxyPort
systemProp.https.proxyUser=USER
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=PASSWORD
```